# Perform procedure when value on datagrid combobox value changs

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a combobox in it. I want to perform the following procedure any time the value on the combobox changes:

```
Dim dblQty As Double
    Dim dblPrice As Double


    For index As Integer = 0 To grdNewInvoice.RowCount - 1

        dblQty = Convert.ToDouble(grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(1).Value)
        dblPrice = Convert.ToDouble(grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(2).Value)

        grdNewInvoice.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value = dblPrice * dblQty

    Next

    Dim dblTotal As Double = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To grdNewInvoice.RowCount - 1
        If grdNewInvoice.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value IsNot "" Then
            dblTotal += CDbl(grdNewInvoice.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
        End If
    Next

    lblTotal.Text = dblTotal.ToString("C")

End Sub
```

I have tried different events: CellEndEdit, CellContentClick, but none worked for me.  What event can I use.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845487%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/49a23caa-6481-405b-8a00-74ecf053f777/what-is-the-dirty-state-of-a-datagridview-combobox?forum=winforms